# Form submission failed:: Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header​

Tags: amp-html

I'd like to use `amp-form` for a form submission. Sending text/data to database within same domain.

Upon a simple form submission I get this uncaught error:
`Form submission failed:: Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header​​​`.

I've Googled and most answers have pointed me to set header within .htaccess document like so:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

I'm continuing to search for an answer.

Comment: Have it solve your issue by adding header('AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: URL'); ?

Comment: Yes It has @Mr.Rebot. I've found it out a week ago but still It got me to a deeper problems with using `amp-form`. So I've decided to circumvent amp's page with a form.

Comment: I am facing similar issue during form submission by post method. Error :  Uncaught Error: Form submission failed:: Returned AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin is not equal to the current: http://localhost/WebApplication1/DefaultAMP.aspx vs http://localhost​​​  .Please suggest me exact headers needed to be set in this case.

Comment: I had the same issue even after setting AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin to the value of the __amp_source_origin param - watching the network traffic showed the header was being set in the response.  Setting the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header value to AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin solved it; not sure but I suspect this tells the browser to pass that header through to the client-side JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, AMP requires certain headers to be present in cross-origin HTTP responses, including `AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin`.

See the [CORS Requests in AMP](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-cors-requests.md) documentation for the complete list.

Comment: If you'd like to learn more about implementing CORS for a specific platform [follow this link](https://enable-cors.org/server.html).